# Proper way of invoking a function to validate data before submitting a form

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

In my understanting, I have two options to do this:

A) On the HTML form, assign a function on the "onsubmit" attribute, and use that function to return false if something goes wrong. For submitting the form, a submit-type button can be used.

B) Have a non-submit button, that triggers a javascript function on-click; then, from that function, do some "form.submit();" call and force the submition.

Is there a practical difference between these two methods / another prefered method of doing this? Pro - Cons, etc? For now, I just see them as being just a matter of taste,but if there's a functional difference it might come handy knowing it!

thanks a lot

Comment: I've always used option B.  If someone does know the inner workings, I'd also like to know the difference between two options within option B.  The first option is to use type="button" on the html button, and the second is to leave that alone and do $('#selector').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault // Then do stuff });

Answer (score 1):

you also may use "onchange" event listener for not allowing enter invalid data in form